# How to switch user(su) in docker command

Tags: kubernetes

l want to launch a container with non-root user, but l cannot modify the origin Dockerfile, Or l know l can do something like `Run useradd xx` then `User xx` in Dockerfile to achieve that.
What l am doing now is modifying the yaml file like the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-pod
    image: xxx
    command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - |
          useradd xx -s /bin/sh;
          su -l xx; // this line is not working
          sleep 1000000;
```

when l exec into the pod, the default is still the root user, anyone can help with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share error code when deploying Pod above

Comment: No, there is no error accurred. The phenomenon is just `su -l xx;` not switch to xx after it executed.

Comment: You shouldn't need `kubectl exec` in normal operation.  Can you describe more how you're using it?  How would you accomplish this on a local Linux host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use security context as like below

```
   securityContext:
     runAsUser: 1000
     runAsGroup: 3000
     fsGroup: 2000
```

**Reference:** https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#podsecuritycontext-v1-core

[image]

---

> EDIT:

If you wanted to change the user in you container than, you can add extra layer of dockerfile, check below

Add dockerfile layer,

```
   FROM <your_image>
   RUN adduser newuser
   USER newuser
   :       
   :
```

Now use above custom image in your kubernetes.

Comment: l know this way can login as user 1000, but what l want is a username(not integer)

Comment: @Rosmee YOu can add new docker image layer. and use that image in your kubernetes.

Comment: yes l know that, but as i said above, l cannot modify the original image, l need to switch user dynamically

Answer (score 3):

+1 to [dahiya_boy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64708860/7108457) answer however I'd like to add also my 3 cents to what was already said.

I've reproduced your case using popular `nginx` image. I also modified a bit commands from your example so that home directory for the user `xxx` is created as well as some other commands for debugging purpose.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-pod
    image: nginx
    command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - |
          useradd xxx -ms /bin/bash;
          su xxx && echo $?;
          whoami;
          sleep 1000000;
```

After successfully applying the above `yaml` we can run:

```
$ kubectl logs my-pod
0
root
```

As you can see the exit status of the `echo $?` command is `0` which means that previous command in fact ran successfully. Even more: the construction with `&&` implies that second command is run if and only if the first command completed successfully (with exit status equal to `0`). If `su xxx` didn't work, `echo $?` would never run.

Nontheless, the very next command, which happens to be `whoami`, prints the actual user that is meant to run all commands in the container and which was defined in the original image. So no matter how many times you run `su xxx`, all subsequent commands will be run as user `root` (or another, which was defined in the `Dockerfile` of the image). So basically the only way to override it on kubernetes level is using already mentioned `securityContext`:

> You need to use security context as like below
>
> ```
>    securityContext:
>      runAsUser: 1000
>      runAsGroup: 3000
>      fsGroup: 2000
> ```

However I understand that you cannot use this method if you have not previously defined your user in a custom image. This can be done if a user with such `uid` already exists.

So to the best of my knowledge, it's impossible to do this the way you presented in your question and it's not an issue or a bug. It simply works this way.

If you `kubectl exec` to your newly created `Pod` in the interactive mode, you can see that everything works perfectly, user was successfully added and you can switch to this user without any problem:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti my-pod -- /bin/sh
# tail -2 /etc/passwd
nginx:x:101:101:nginx user,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
xxx:x:1000:1000::/home/xxx:/bin/bash
# su xxx
xxx@my-pod:/$ pwd
/
xxx@my-pod:/$ cd
xxx@my-pod:~$ pwd
/home/xxx
xxx@my-pod:~$ whoami
xxx
xxx@my-pod:~$
```

But it doesn't mean that by running `su xxx` as one of the commands, provided in a `Pod` `yaml` definition, you will permanently change the default user.

I'd like to emphasize it again. In your example `su -l xxx` runs successfully. It's not true that it doesn't work. In other words: 1. container is started as user `root` 2. user `root` runs `su -l xxx` and once completed successfully, exits 3. user `root` runs `whoami`.

So the only reasonable solution is, already mentioned by @dahiya_boy, adding an extra layer and create a custom image.

As to:

> @Rosmee YOu can add new docker image layer. and use that image in your
> kubernetes. – dahiya_boy 18 hours ago
>
> **yes l know that, but as i said above, l cannot modify the original
> image**, l need to switch user dynamically – Rosmee 17 hours ago

You say *"I cannot modify the original image"* and this is exactly what custom image is about. No one is talking here about modifying the original image. It remains untouched. By writing your own `Dockerfile` and e.g. by adding in it an extra user and setting it as a default one, you don't modify the original image at all, but build a new custom image on top of it. That's how it works and that's the way it is meant to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really makes sense to me! But my situation is that l need to launch a container with specified default user, the username is defined by user every time he/she wants to launch this container. So the image/Dockerfile is stable, is there a way to solve that?

Comment: And l know `securityContext ` is a good way to do that and l have already tried that... But the problem is that it only supports uid which means when l exec into the pod, the default user is like `l have no name@` because we only specify the uid and the actual user is not created..